# Efficient method to store tree-structure in MPI for game tree traversal

Tags: mpi

I have implemented the game tree traversal of a particular game in C++ with MPI support. I have used BerkeleyDB to store the game tree. It works great on a single node but not in the cluster. After a lot of experiments I noticed that it's due to overhead of the BerkeleyDB.

Can anybody suggest a BDB alternative that is suitable for cluster and MPI?

Thanks,